# Modifying Windows Pe-EXE icon and version information with Pefile.py

Tags: python, icons, exe, portable-executable

I'm using Ero Carrera's [pefile.py](https://github.com/erocarrera/pefile/) on a Linux webserver to retrieve the version information of Windows Exe files.

Is it possible with Pefile, which also has write support, to modify the Exe icon and the version information?